# Terraform | Upgrade to 0.12 error Reference to "count" in non-counted context

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to upgrade terraform from 0.11 to 0.12 but receiving error:

```
 Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

  on main.tf line 33, in data "aws_subnet" "public":
  33:   id = data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids[count.index]

The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.
```

Here is my part of code:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "public" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Tier = "public"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "public" {  
  id = data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids[count.index]
}
```

Maybe someone know how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your underlying goal here is to retrieve the full set of attributes for each of your subnets that are marked as `Tier = public`. Here's a different way to do that using features from Terraform 0.12.6:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "public" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Tier = "public"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "public" {  
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids

  id = each.value
}
```

With the above, you should find that `data.aws_subnet.public` is a map from subnet id to the attributes of that particular subnet.

---

The reason for the error in your case is that you used `count.index` but didn't set the `count` argument, and so there is no count index to return.

The `count`-based equivalent of the above, which is more similar to your original example, would be this:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "public" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Tier = "public"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "public" {  
  count = length(data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids)

  id = sort(data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids)[count.index]
}
```

The result of this is very similar to the `for_each`-based example I gave above, but with one significant difference: in this case `data.aws_subnet.public` will be a *list* of subnet objects, ordered by the lexical ordering of their subnet ids. That will usually make the result harder to use elsewhere in the configuration, so I'd suggest using the `for_each` approach unless there's a specific reason why you need a list.

(If you use a map and then later find that you need a list in a *specific context*, you can always use `values(data.aws_subnet.public)` to take the values from the map, in the same lexical order.)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, when I run code with "for_each" I get the same error, but with "sort" works.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I made an editing error when I was copying the code examples around. I'll fix the `for_each` example now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are save me!